# How to use Java Class as parameter in a constructor of another class

Tags: java, class

I have two classes HighScoreDialog and HighScoreTableModel

I need to modify the  HighScoreDialog constructor so that it takes a single HighScoreTableModel argument. I also need to modify the rest of the method to use this
model rather than creating a new one.

This is the relevant code of the two classes with my attempt.

```
public class HighScore_Dialog extends JDialog {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public HighScore_Dialog(Class HighScoreTableModel) {
            JTable table = new JTable(HighScoreTableModel);


public class HighScoreTableModel implements TableModel{
```

It obviously does not work I have also tired Class `<T>` but that didn't work either

Comment: how about? public HighScore_Dialog(HighScoreTableModel highScoreTableModel){
   JTable table = new JTable(highScoreTableModel);
}

Comment: Why `Class` at all?  Why not just `HighScoreTableModel model` as the parameter?

Comment: Why the perceived need for this? Also why not have your HighScoreTableModel class extend AbstractTableModel? If you don't do this, you have to implement all the notification methods yourself. This question seems like it might actually be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @krackmoe Thanks a lot it worked I tried something like this using eclipses tips But could not quite understand how to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this constructor:

```
public HighScore_Dialog(HighScoreTableModel highScoreTableModel) {
     JTable table = new JTable(highScoreTableModel);
}
```